# Infinite xhr-streaming, websocket and info calls in nodejs angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, sockets, ubuntu

I have deployed my application developed in NodeJS + Angular8 on Ubuntu 18.04 using AWS EC2. Application runs fine but I am seeing infinite websocket and xhr_streaming related request keeps going as attached below. How it can be stopped?
ps:- There is no any socket related functionality implemented in my applicatin.

It seems because of this cpu utilization is going high and server stops after some time. I get below error in apache logs.

```
caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I am trying to resolve it by following the instructions given below, but its not yet resolved.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3947

https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/308

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this an angular production build..?

Comment: @MikeOne yes, its happening on production site.